# How to access the nested object in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have handle click and I want to access the className of the div element, how can I do that

1. this is the element i want to get the div className

   ```
    <div className="milad">
        <IconButton
           style={{outline:'none', color: 'white', float:'right', marginRight:'20px', marginTop: "5px"}}
                   className = "iconButton"
        >menu
           <MenuIcon/>
        </IconButton>
    </div>
   ```
2. this is my

   ```
   checkHandleClick = (event) => {
       console.log(event);
   }
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={((e) => this.checkHandleClick(e))}>
   -----some code------
   </ClickAwayListener>
   ```

I want to access this [Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ji5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ref for it.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Or if you're using hooks

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do using `event.target.className`

```
checkHandleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.className);
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={((e) => this.checkHandleClick(e))}>
-----some code------
</ClickAwayListener>
```